Merge rows while keep changes in columns specified
I currently have a pyspark dataframe like this:



Key
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
col_changed




X
2
1
2
3
Col1


X
3
1
2
6
Col4


X
3
2
2
3
Col2



There are a lot of duplicates per Key, i would like to merge them all together and keep the value of the Column that is specified in "col_changed" column. The rest of the column will be exact copy of one another (like Col3 here) so taking the first value is fine.
Example outcome in this case:



Key
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4




X
2
2
2
6




hi hhp, use Pivot function
